# How can I run Arma 2: Operation Arrowhead with BMF, PFC and ACR DLCs without Steam?

Tags: steam, arma-2

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to run Arma 2: OA with BAF, PMC and ACR DLCs without running steam.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are 3 ways to select or deselect mods/DLCs in ARMA 2 and play it without Steam:

1. From 'Mod Configuration' menu by starting the game directly from `ArmA2OA.exe`. You should find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\arma 2 operation arrowhead`. (Assuming you installed it in Steam files, it should be there)
2. By using launcher commands. This can be quiet confusing and alternative for No.1 if no other choice available. First make a shortcut (to desktop or anywhere you like) of `ArmA2AO.exe`. And then right click the shortcut you have created, **NOT** the default *ARMA2:AO* Steam shortcut on the desktop and choose Properties. Add the following at the end of the address in the *target* box:

   `-mod=PMC;BAF;ACR;`

   I don't know if the DLC file names are all started with '@' like a mod file (exp: `@DayZ` for DayZ mod file) but add '@' if they do like this:

   `-mod=@PMC;@BAF;@ACR;`

   For more info, click [**THIS**](http://www.armaholic.com/plug.php?e=faq&q=18).
3. By using alternative programs like [Six Updater](http://www.six-updater.net/). By using this program you can create multiple game profiles and set what mods/DLC to use for each profile. It also got some handy mods updater too **BUT** it is quiet difficult to get to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start *ArmAOA.exe* straight from Windows Explorer (I assume you are using Windows). As for starting it with BAF, PMC, ACR, you are going to need to add some parameters to start it up.

The best way to do this, is to open up windows explorer (My Computer or whatever) and in the navigation bar, to type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\arma 2 operation arrowhead" (if necessary replace C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\ with the Steam installation folder). Next, right click on *ArmA2OA.exe* and choose *Copy* and go to wherever you want a shortcut to appear and right-click and choose *Paste shortcut*. Now, on this newly created shortcut, right-click it and choose *Properties* and add the following **to the end** of what currently exists in the text box labelled *target*:

> -mod=PMC;BAF;ACR;

I'm unsure whether this is the correct syntax (athough I'm pretty sure it is) but I can't test this because I've not got my PC with me at the moment, and also I don't own ACR yet and I'm just guessing that its folder is going to be called ACR. But, try this and get back to me with the results.